# Checking if a member has a certain role

Tags: discord-jda

I'm trying to only allow a certain role to view a section of the help command.
I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work and it just shows the default help embed:

```
List<Role> staff = event.getGuild().getRolesByName("Staff", true);

                if (event.getGuild().getSelfMember().getRoles().contains(staff)) {

                    final EmbedBuilder ahelp = new EmbedBuilder();

                    ahelp.setTitle("Commands List", null);
                    ahelp.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    ahelp.addField("Member:", "*help: Returns with this message." +
                            "\n*bugreport <Bug>: Creates a new bug report." +
                            "\n*suggest <Suggestion>: Creates a new suggestion."
                            , false);
                    ahelp.addField("Staff:", "*ban <Member> [Reason]: Bans a member." +
                            "\n*mute <Member> [Reason]: Mutes a member." +
                            "\n*kick <Member> [Reason]: Kicks a member." +
                            "\n*unmute <Member>: Unmutes a member."
                            , false);
                    ahelp.setFooter("Bot • " + dtf.format(now));

                    event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage(ahelp.build()).queue();
                    return;

                } else {

                    final EmbedBuilder help = new EmbedBuilder();

                    help.setTitle("Commands List", null);
                    help.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    help.addField("Member:", "*help: Returns with this message." +
                            "\n*bugreport <Bug>: Creates a new bug report." +
                            "\n*suggest <Suggestion>: Creates a new suggestion."
                            , false);
                    help.setFooter("Bot • " + dtf.format(now));

                    event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage(help.build()).queue();
                    return;

                }
```

If there is a better way, or if you know how to answer my question please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to check if a `List<Role>` contains another `List<Role>`. This is not how `contains` works. The correct usage would be with a `Role` object rather than a `List<Role>` object.

Since I assume you are looking for just the fact that the member has a role with the name `"Staff"` you can use the `Stream` API:

```java
public boolean hasRole(Member member, String name) {
    return member.getRoles().stream().map(Role::getName).anyMatch(name::equalsIgnoreCase);
}

if (hasRole(event.getGuild().getSelfMember(), "Staff")) {
   // ... your code here ...
}
```

You also only check the "self member" which means you only check the roles of the bot itself rather than the roles of the user. I think you might want to use `event.getMember()` instead?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I was just using `event.getSelfMember()` for something else and got confused between the two.

Comment: I'm also getting this error: `Incompatible types: Role is not convertible to String` Is there a way to fix this?